# using modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, spyder

I want to use some modules in python with the software Spyder and I installed some modules like panda on my computer. One of the modules I installed is matplotlib_venn which I downloaded from pypi.python.org. I installed the same way as panda and it says the installation was succesfull but when I try to import the matplotlib_venn module as followed:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
```

This gives me the error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/gebruiker/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/gebruiker/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-20ac6695c8d8>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/gebruiker/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/gebruiker/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/gebruiker/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 1, in <module>
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib_venn'
```

If I import panda as pd there is no problem, can someone try to explain how this is possible or maybe connect me to the right forum where this is already discussed? I tried to find it on my own but my knowledge of this is not really good.

Thanks already

Comment: pip install matplotlib_venn

Comment: It gives: requirement already satisfied. Like I said I already installed it and I was able to install and use Panda but for some reason this wont work

Comment: I did that but if I try to import it, it still gives no module name. Is it possible that it is in a different location? I have the feeling that spyder reeds the modules out of my anaconda\lib\site-packages location but that the module is installed in python\python36\lib\sitepackages location

Comment: so simple and yet it works, thank you for helping me through this silly problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the installation location is not where python is expecting the module files. a quick work around it to just copy the files and directories to the expected location, in this case it seems to be looking for the files in:

```
C:\Users\gebruiker\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder
```

So just copy the files there from the python lib directory.